# Will sandbox Auto-renewable subscription survive app reinstallation

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, subscription

Currently I testing Auto-renewable subscription in my app. Once I reinstalled app I cannot get my subscription back.

**My question:**

Will sandbox Auto-renewable subscription survive app reinstallation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do survive an app reinstallation. The user might need to trigger ["Restore purchases"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions) (which you really should provide in your app), but in my testing that usually wasn't necessary as after a reinstall all in-app purchases are already present in the App Store receipt.

Your code must be able to parse the App Store receipt to detect that subscription (and read its expiry date), of course.

Comment: [System will restore Auto-renewable subscription](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2), or I'm missing something?

Comment: @CAMOBAP: In my tests with the sandbox, it wasn't always restored by the system automatically. That might have to do with the frequent sandbox App Store outages and problems, though. But let's give them the benefit of the doubt and assume that the auto-renewable subscription restoration _does_ work flawless in the field: then you don't need to offer a _"Restore purchases"_ functionality.